# Extract data from older version of microsoft access mdb using pyodbc

Tags: python, excel, ms-access, pyodbc

I have a lots of access .mdb file that I need to process using python and that data to store in excel file. Currently I am testing pyodbc library, everything works fine with test databases created in access 2016 (code to connect to db below), but with older version mdb it does not work(I did not confirmed with which access it was created), error like: "cannot open db created in previous version(-1019) blah, blah, blah..."

```
conn_str = (
   r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
   r'DBQ=C:\path\to\mydb.accdb;'
   )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
for table_info in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
   print(table_info.table_name)
```

Is there a way to bypass this error, or any other library you could suggest just to extract that data?

So far I have found one solution that works, but the solution is not convenient when working with large number of databases, basically it is possible to open each mdb file in excel and than do with data whatever you need to, but I would prefer some more elegant solution if possible.

Current way to extract data: [Access 2013 - Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116593/access-2013-cannot-open-a-database-created-with-a-previous-version-of-your-app)

Any idea would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: If you install a 32-bit version of Python you could try using it with `r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};`